# How to distinguish whitespace in string after using "read" in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, whitespace

I'm trying to writing a vim-like editor using shell. And I find that I cannot distinguish whitespace. I read 4 character because some special characters like arrows have 3 bytes. But it will be a mess if you enter keys at a fast speed.

So how can I distinguish space? (If you can tell me a better way to deal with the "entering too fast" problem will be nicer.)

```
while read -rsN1 key
do
    
    if [ $key==$'\e' ];then
        read -sN1 -t 0.0001 k1
        read -sN1 -t 0.0001 k2
        read -sN1 -t 0.0001 k3
        key+=${k1}${k2}${k3}
    fi
        
    case $key in 
        $'\e[A')
             echo "up" ;;
        ' ')
             echo "space" ;;  #It doesn't work here!!!
        i)
             echo "insert" ;;

    esac
done
```

Comment: Why are you reading in individual characters rather than an entire line of input ?

Comment: A text editor needs to immediately react to every key press. It can't wait for Enter...

Comment: [Good Discussion of raw mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/537296/197080) that may help with your termios choices. (but overarching question is why choose to write an editor in shell? Far too slow. It's fine for an exercise, but for serious use it may be troublesome when pasting large blocks of text)

Comment: I don't think it a good task to write editor in shell either. It's just our homework... quite meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.
Instead of trying that there are a lot of things you can learn when using vim/vi/vim.exe/vi.exe in any operating system (Windows cygwin/mingw, AIX, Linux HP-UX/OSF1/IRIX/SunOS/UNIX)
Hence try learning vi.

However I have updated your code only for my knowledge transfer:
Here goes my coding:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Use any one of the following keys:"
UP=$(echo $'\U2190')
#echo -n $'\U2190' | od -bc
#echo -e "\0342\0206\0220" # LEFT
LEFT=$(echo $'\U2191')
#echo -e "\0342\0206\0221" # UP
RIGHT=$(echo $'\U2192')
#echo -e "\0342\0206\0222" # RIGHT
DOWN=$(echo $'\U2193')
#echo -e "\0342\0206\0223" # DOWN
echo SPACEBAR
while read -rsN1 key
do
 if [ $'\e' == "$key" ]
 then
 read -sN1 -t 0.0001 k1
 read -sN1 -t 0.0001 k2
 read -sN1 -t 0.0001 k3
 key+=${k1}${k2}${k3}
 fi
 case $key in
 $'[A')
 echo -n "$UP"
 ;;
 $'[B')
 echo -n "$DOWN"
 ;;
 $'[C')
 echo -n "$RIGHT"
 ;;
 $'[D')
 echo -n "$LEFT"
 ;;
 ' ')
 echo -n " "
 ;;
 #It doesn't work here!!!
 i)
 echo "insert"
 ;;
 esac
done
```

My output:

```
$ 73172247.sh
Use any one of the following keys:
SPACEBAR
↑↓←→↓↑ ↑↑ ↑ →←↑
Example pdf:
https://www.jics.utk.edu/files/images/csure-reu/PDF-DOC/VI-TUTORIAL.pdf
Textpad.exe/notepad++.exe at windows
gedit at Linux.
```